# emitting to single client socket io 1.3.2

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I've looked at several answers on here, but I think they are referring to older versions of socket.io as their solutions have not worked for me. I'm getting the data back in the browser with

```
io.emit('update', data)
```

but it's emitting to all clients so the same data is showing up in multiple windows when I go to the same URL. Do I have to store the client id somewhere upon connection or can I just get it back before emitting? Please be specific. I tried a few other solutions from SO, but I got a lot of ReferenceError 'id' is not defined or sockets instead of socket.

Server set up and connection:

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app)
var io = require('socket.io')(server)

app.get('/aPath', function (req, res, next) {
        res.writeHead(200)

    var data = {
        "val1":  req.query.val1,
        "val2":  req.query.val2,
        "val3":  req.query.val3,
        "val4":  req.query.val4,
        "val5":  req.query.val5,
        "val6":  req.query.val6,
    }

    /*console.log(io.sockets.id)*/

    //io.to(io.sockets.id).emit('update', data)
    //io.sockets.socket(id).emit('update', data)
    io.emit('update', data)
    res.end("OK")
})

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('websocket user connected')
});
```

Comment: You have to somehow correlate the restful client with the socket client. Once you do that, you can emit your data.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand what you mean 'correlate the restful client with the socket client' Can you explain further?

Comment: Read my answer. basically make sure you know who the third party client is sending information about. if you 1000 active users, you want to send it to the correct user, so you have to correlate the correct socket user with the response from the third party client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a third-party client is sending the info via a restful interface, you will need to include reference data for the client in that request in the form of a header or query string.

I suggest using Redis to store the active socket users for quick reference. This will allow you to have multiple applications in deployment that use a singular redis instance to keep the data in sync. You can also do the same in app memory, but that just doesn't scale well.

first, you need to use middleware to authenticate user and cache the socket.id

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');

io.use(function(socket, next){
  // validate user
  // cache user with socket.id
  var userId = validatedUser;
  socket.handshake.userId = userId;
  redis.set(userId, socket.id, function (err, res) {
       next()
  });
});
```

next handle all socket communication

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('websocket user connected');

    //next handle all socket communication
    socket.on('endpoint', function (payload) {
        //do stuff
        socket.emit('endpoint.response', {/*data*/});
    });

    //Then remove socket.id from cache
    socket.on('disconnect', function (payload) {
        //remove user.id from cache
        redis.del(socket.handshake.userId, function (err, res) {
             console.log('user with %s disconnected', socket.id);
        });
    });
});
```

Handle third party event.

```
app.get('/aPath', function (req, res, next) {
    // get user from third party
    var userId = req.query.userId

    var data = {
        "val1":  req.query.val1,
        "val2":  req.query.val2,
        "val3":  req.query.val3,
        "val4":  req.query.val4,
        "val5":  req.query.val5,
        "val6":  req.query.val6,
    };

    // get cached socketId from userId
    redis.get(userId, function (err, socketId) {
        // return ok to third party;
        res.status(200).send("OK");
        only emit if socketid still exists
        if (err || !socketId) return;
        // now emit to user
        io.to(socketId).emit('update', data):
    });
});
```

Comment: I updated my post to include a little more context for the emit statement. A third party sends the get request and data to aPath, then the websocket emits that back to the connected client (not the same client who sent the get request) where the data is rendered. How can I get the socket id in that context?